# java: error after adding libraray

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to add a library (specifically, [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg)).

I copied these jarfiles into `app/libs`:

> itextg-5.5.4.jar
>   itextg-5.5.4-javadocs.jar
>   itextg-5.5.4-resources.jar

Then, I right-clicked on the first of them in Android Studio and chose "add as library". Then I checked that `build.gradle` in my `app` folder contains the dependecy `compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')` and used "Clean Project". Now I'm using the library in my code, but when I try to build it, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK com/itextpdf/text/AGPL.txt
    File 1: C:\Users\XXX\AndroidStudioProjects\HandballEventLogger\app\libs\itextg-5.5.4-sources.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\XXX\AndroidStudioProjects\HandballEventLogger\app\libs\itextg-5.5.4-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

try to find a project property which add these jars to the `java build path` same as in Eclipse